# MATLAB optimization function variable assignment in anonymous function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I have an optimization problem in MATLAB and I'd like to be able to write an anonymous function to pass to the optimization function.

The function I am minimizing is a function of `x`, but I am required to pass it `y` where

```
y = zeros(N,1); 
y(idx) = x;
```

That is I am passing a vector `y` that is zero apart from at indexes `idx` where it is `x` and `x` is the variable I am optimizing over.

The key step is the assignment `y(idx)=x` which is tricky because assignments can't be done in an anonymous function.

I need to do this as efficiently as possible (`N` and `idx` will be large.)

I have an anonymous function that works as follows

```
iif = @(varargin) varargin{2 * find([varargin{1:2:end}], 1, 'first')}();
y = arrayfun(@(k) iif(ismember(k,idx),x(idx==k),true,0),0:N-1)';
```

but it is slow compared to writing a simple external function.

Now I can use the simple external function, but would like to know if I am missing a trick to make a faster anonymous function.

Edited to add a more complete example.

```
N = 100;
idx = [2 7 9]';
x = rand(size(idx));
y = zeros(N,1);
y(idx) = x;
```

Comment: Is this all you are doing?  y = [zeros(idx-1,1);x;zeros(N-idx,1)].  Where is the idx coming from? How is that being passed into your functions?

Comment: Don’t use an anonymous function if your code is even slightly complex. You might be able to figure out some way to do this, but you’ll have unreadable, unmaintainable, slow code. All so you can say “yay! I did it in one line!”

Comment: You can annonymize any function. `fun=@(x)sin(x)` or `fun=@(x)function_that_is_long_and_you_sensibly_wrote_it_in_a_separate_file(x)`

Comment: "I need to do this as efficiently as possible" then you don't want an anonymous function. The anonymous function you've currently shown is not efficient, it uses `arrayfun` which is basically a loop in disguise (proper loops with pre-allocated outputs are not slow in MATLAB) and parsing of `varargin`, and `find`... if you wrote it out in a stand-alone function you would be able to debug and `profile` your code to increase its efficiency. Aside from that, without a [mcve] it's hard to help you, we don't even know if `idx` is logical or index values.

Comment: @CrisLuengo. I think it's a matter of taste. I mostly write code for my own use and prefer a functional programming style. I like my code to look like math. I add lots of comments so I can work out what I did if I every need to go back to it. I prefer very short variable names like the math. And in testing, I have found that using anonymous functions and a functional programming style is often, but not always, faster.

Comment: @AnderBiguri. See previous comment. One reason I like to keep everything together in one file is that it's easier for me to maintain (when I am the only user.)

Comment: I certainly disagree with it being easier to maintain, but in MATLAB you can have function definitions in the end of your script, so even if it were, its not really a reason to not do it.

Comment: “I think it's a matter of taste.” No, it’s the wisdom of many decades of advances in programming. If you need a comment to explain what code does and what you were thinking when you implemented it, then it’s not clear code, and will be hard to maintain. Not only for other people, but also for yourself 6 months down the line. Comments are to explain the logic, not the code itself. The code itself must be easily understandable. Preferring a functional programming style is fine. But that doesn’t mean using anonymous functions for everything. It also means you shouldn’t be using MATLAB.

Comment: @AnderBiguri That is a blatant misuse of anonymous functions. You can just use a handle to the named function in that case: `fun=@function_that_is_long_and_you_sensibly_wrote_it_in_a_separate_file`. Anonymous functions (“lambdas”) serve mostly to capture local variables (“state”): `fun=@(x)foobar(x, 5, 'baz')`

Comment: @CrisLuengo fair point, I was indeed more thinking about the second example you just given, indeed if the fun has the inputs the optimizer needs, then just pass a handle, agreed!

Comment: @AnderBiguri I know you know this. I wrote it mostly to educate OP, in line with my assertion that using anonymous functions is not functional programming.